# How to create a dialect of the draft 2020-12 JSON Schema meta-schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to create a dialect of the draft-2020-12 meta-schema. I want the dialect to prohibit the use of any of the properties (title, description, default, etc.) in the "meta-data" meta-schema. In other words, I want the meta-data vocabulary deleted from the "main" meta-schema:

```
"$vocabulary": {
    ...
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/meta-data": true
```

How to do that? What are the list of steps needed to create this new meta-schema dialect? @Jason Desrosiers wrote a terrific list of steps (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63797644/1248535) for creating a dialect of the draft04 meta-schema. I am guessing that the list of steps for creating a dialect of the draft-2020-12 meta-schema is quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a pretty good example [in the spec](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-example-meta-schema-with-vo).

Starting with 2019-09, we broke the meta-schema into several, one for each vocabulary.  The first thing to do is remove the things you don't want.

Start with the 2020-12 base meta-schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$vocabulary": {
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/core": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/applicator": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/unevaluated": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/validation": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/meta-data": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/format-annotation": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/content": true
  },
  "$dynamicAnchor": "meta",

  "title": "Core and Validation specifications meta-schema",
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "meta/core"},
    {"$ref": "meta/applicator"},
    {"$ref": "meta/validation"},
    {"$ref": "meta/meta-data"},
    {"$ref": "meta/format-annotation"},
    {"$ref": "meta/content"}
  ],
  "type": ["object", "boolean"]
  // there's some other "deprecated" stuff in here that you likely don't need
}
```

You don't want the meta-data vocabulary, so remove references to that.  You should also change the `$id` because this is your meta-schema now, not the draft 2020-12 meta-schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://your.domain/meta-schema/or/something",
  "$vocabulary": {
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/core": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/applicator": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/unevaluated": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/validation": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/format-annotation": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/content": true
  },
  "$dynamicAnchor": "meta",

  "title": "Core and Validation specifications meta-schema",
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "meta/core"},
    {"$ref": "meta/applicator"},
    {"$ref": "meta/validation"},
    {"$ref": "meta/format-annotation"},
    {"$ref": "meta/content"}
  ],
  "type": ["object", "boolean"]
  // there's some other "deprecated" stuff in here that you likely don't need
}
```

That removes the *definition* of those keywords, but it doesn't disallow them.  Draft 2020-12 permits the inclusion of unknown keywords, so with this anyone could still just add `title`.  What's more, since we've removed the definition for `title`, they can add it with whatever value they want:

```json
{
  "title": true
}
```

This would be a valid schema according to your meta-schema.

To disallow those keywords, you have several options.

- disallow only those specific keywords
- disallow all unknown keywords

#### Disallow only those keywords

For this you have several options, but I think this is probably the simplest:

```json
{
  // rest of meta-schema
  "properties": {
    "title": false,
    ...
  }
}
```

It basically says that no value for these properties is valid, effectively requiring that they're not present.

#### Disallow all unknown keywords

For this approach, you'll add `unevaluatedProperties: false` to the meta-schema.  This will disallow any keyword not defined in one of the meta-schemas listed in the `allOf`.

```json
{
  // rest of meta-schema
  "unevaluatedProperties": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So I placed the new meta-schema in a file named new-meta-schema-main.json and then created a JSON Schema file (named schema.json) that conforms to the new meta-schema. I believe that the value of $schema in schema.json should be the value of $id in new-meta-schema-main.json, right?

Comment: That's correct.